# Scheduled Query at two time slots daily with Big Query UI

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to schedule a query in **Big Query** at **8:00 am** and **10:00 am** on a daily basis. Is it possible to define this rule using **Big Query UI** and **the custom scheduler** ? I have tried : **"every days 08:00, 10:00"** but it does not work.

Thanks

Comment: While you cannot do this with BigQueryUI - you can do this and many more with Magnus - Workflow Automator which is part of [Potens.io](https://potensio.zendesk.com/) Suite - supports all BigQuery, Cloud Storage and most of Google APIs as well as multiple simple utility type Tasks like BigQuery Task, Export to Storage Task, Loop Task and many many more along with advanced scheduling, triggering, etc.. Also available at [Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio). Disclosure: I am GDE for Google Cloud and creator of those tools and leader on Potens team

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct option to do it, you can try below. Let me know if it works. Below is link for documentation for custom schedule.[Link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#formatting_the_schedule)

```
every 2 hours from 08:00 to 10:00
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to schedule a query with those rules. I think the way to go it's to create two scheduled queries on daily basis, one at 8:00 am and the other one at 10:00 am. Also, in order to minimize your maintenance work you can use a view to embed your query.